# Animated Sprite animating more that once in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I was trying to animate a sprite only once but it is animated twice can any one help me with this?? Here is the code

```
    CuttingLineEffect(float x, float y, TiledTextureRegion line_region)
{
    super(x, y, line_region);
    this.animate(60, 1);
    this.mPhysicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(this); 
    this.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);
    this.setPosition(x-this.getWidth()/2-50+this.getWidth()/2,y+50);
}

@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

    if(!set)
    {
        MainMenu.LineList.add(this);
        set = true;
    }
    if(!this.isAnimationRunning() && !time_to_unload)
    {
        time_to_unload = true;

    }


    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Animate() second parameter is how many times you want to loop that animation. because you only want to animate it once you might aswell use.

```
this.animate(60,0);
```

Comment: but this does'nt animate for once it animates for life time of the sprite

Comment: Hmm.. Sorry, What about this.animate(60,false); ?

Comment: this doesn't animate at all :(

Comment: My last guess looking at the sourcecode of AnimatedSprite.

this.animate(60, 0);

Comment: I see there is an onAnimationEnd() method in the iAnimationListener. you could try to implement the method and in that method call stopAnimation() on the sprite... i wonder :P

Answer (score 3):

```
Sprite.animate(100,false);
```

- `100` --> the time duration for each frame
- `false` --> the second parameter is either you want to loop or not.